# How to find out why a specific File is locked on my ESXI Server

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a broken VM on my ESXi Server, after looking for the reason the VM isn't starting I found 4 files locked for some reason even when the VM isn't powered on. When I try to use "vmfsfilelockinfo" on one of the Files, it gives me this message:

*Looking for lock owners on "vmx-abuvm2-3022981746-2.vswp"
Failed to get the lock owners for /vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2/vmx-abuvm2-3022981746-2.vswp
Reason : Could not get the dump information for '/vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2/vmx-abuvm2-3022981746-2.vswp' (rv -1)
Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Could not dump metadata for '/vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2/vmx-abuvm2-3022981746-2.vswp': Inappropriate ioctl for device*

I'm not so such what exactly the problem is, so maybe some could help me with that

Comment: Version: 6.5.0 Update 3 (Build 19092475)

Comment: ESXi 6.5 has reached it's end of life. Upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: Do an `lsof` and look for these files there with `grep`. If nothing shows up, you should reboot the host.

Comment: [root@esxi4:/vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2] lsof | grep /vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2/abuvm2-000008-delta.vmdk

134243      vmx                   FILE                       75   /vmfs/volumes/8a04aeb3-af12c6c2/abuvm2/abuvm2-000008-delta.vmdk

Comment: Now do a `esxcli vm process list` and look for `VMX Cartel ID: 134243`, it should tell you what VM currently holds a lock. If you're running a backup agent proxy (such as Veeam), it can be that proxy having this snapshot open..

Comment: Ok thank you very much, that really helped. At least I know where to lock :)